# FCM Server Key Restriction

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-console

When i create a new project in Firebase console, it generates a cloud messaging api key by default. Take my key per ex:

[image: CM Key on Firebase Console]

This key is also created in the google api managers console, same key per ex:

[image: Key in Google API manager]

It's all good, but I'm gonna be using this key to send pushes on a webpage (FCM API using javascript), so I want to restrict the requests from my website.

The problem is, if I take my key and apply a restriction on it on API manager console, Firebase generates a new key (both in Firebase console - cloud message and API manager console), to be used. The old key that is restricted does not work, I only get HTTP 403 on request, but the new one(unrestricted) works 100%.

So my question is, how to restrict a **FCM Server key**? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

`FCM Server key` does not support restrictions.

The best way is to use the `FCM server key` from your application server, and not from a client like a web page or a web app.
You can then make the application server available to the client via a custom API, and you can control the authentication process between the client and the backend.